# Modeling RLC in OpenModelica. Error - Type mismatch,between Complex and Real

Tags: openmodelica

**EDITED 28-04-2021**

I trying to build a RLC-chain in OpenModelica.
When I entering the several functions in `"equation"`, appears an error (see comments)
I declared some of the variables above, but the errors did not disappear

There are RLC-chain
[image]

There are formulas

[image]

```
  model Lab5
      extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
      type Voltage=Real(unit="V");
      type Current=Real(unit="A");
      type Resistance=Real(unit="Ohm");
      type Capacitance=Real(unit="F");
      type Inductance =Real(unit="H");
      
      parameter Modelica.SIunits.Resistance R=100 "Resistance";
      parameter Modelica.SIunits.Inductance L=1 "Inductance";
      parameter Modelica.SIunits.Voltage Vb=24 "Total DC Voltage";
      parameter Modelica.SIunits.Capacitance C=1e-3 "Capacitance";
      Voltage V;
      Current i_L;
      Current i_R;
      Current i_C;
      Current icomp;
      
    equation
     Z1_f=Modelica.ComplexMath.'sqrt'(Complex(re=-1)*(2*Modelica.Constants.pi*f*L*(1/(2*Modelica.Constants.pi*f*C)));
  **  //Error:
Type mismatch in equation Z1_f=Modelica.ComplexMath.'sqrt'(Complex.'*'.multiply(Complex(-1.0, 0.0),     
    Complex.'constructor'.fromReal(L / C, 0.0))) of type Real=record Complex
      Real re;
      Real im;
    end Complex;.**


      Z2_f=R;
      KPF=Z2_f/(Z1_f+Z2_f);
      APF=ModelicaReference.Operators.'abs(KPF)';
      FPF=Modelica.ComplexMath.arg(KPF);
    
      V = i_R * R;
      C * der(V) = i_C;
      L * der(i_L) = Vb - V;
      i_L = i_R + i_C;
      annotation(
        uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));
    end Lab5;
```

I tried to change the syntax and made this code:

```
 Z1_f=Modelica.ComplexMath.'sqrt'(Complex*Complex(re=2*Modelica.Constants.pi*f*L*(1/(2*Modelica.Constants.pi*f*C))));
```

But now this error:

```
Operator overloading requires exactly one matching expression, but found 0 expressions:
```

But if I assign a complex to one complex in a parenthesis to another complex, thereby assigning 1 argument (not 0, as in the previous error), then the error again refers to the incorrectly composed constructor and the conversion from complex to real.

```
Z1_f=Modelica.ComplexMath.'sqrt'(Complex(Complex(re=(2*Modelica.Constants.pi*f*L*(1/(2*Modelica.Constants.pi*f*C))))));

The are 2 big errors:
 Type mismatch for positional argument 1 in Complex(re=Complex.'constructor'.fromReal(L / C, 0.0)). The argument has type:
  record Complex
  Real re;
  Real im;
end Complex;
expected type:
  Real

Complex.'constructor'.fromReal(re=Complex.'constructor'.fromReal(L / C, 0.0)). The argument has type:
  record Complex
  Real re;
  Real im;
end Complex;
expected type:
  Real
```

How I can to solve this problem between the complex and real variablesO?
Because in Modelica a lot of equations between complex and real datas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like homework, so I will give you some hints.

- Instead of defining pi, use Modelica.Constants.pi.
- ModelicaReference is just a library for documentation you cannot use any of the (quoted) operators from there, remove ModelicaReference.Operators. and the quotes
- You need to declare *all* the variables that appear in the equation section, with correct type (Real or Complex), you are now missing a lot of them
- ModelicaReference.Operators.'abs(KPF)' -> abs(KPF)
- as far as I see you are using complex numbers, for that you need to use type Complex
- For operators on Complex you use: [Complex operators](https://doc.modelica.org/Modelica%203.2.3/Resources/helpOM/Complex.html) and [Modelica.ComplexMath](https://doc.modelica.org/Modelica%203.2.3/Resources/helpOM/Modelica.ComplexMath.html), i.e. Modelica.ComplexMath.'sqrt'(Complex(re=-1, im=0))

Comment: Yes, some of the errors disappeared, which is good. 
But the following error occurred in this code line:


Z1_f=Modelica.ComplexMath.'sqrt'(Complex(re=-1))*(2*Modelica.Constants.pi*f*L*(1/(2*Modelica.Constants.pi*f*C)));


Error:
 Type mismatch in equation Z1_f=Complex.'*'.multiply(Complex(6.123031769111886e-017, 1.0), Complex.'constructor'.fromReal(L / C, 0.0)) of type Real=record Complex
  Real re;
  Real im;
end Complex;.

Comment: Please make a new post (or edit the original one) with the changed model so I can see the code. As far as I can tell you have Complex *  Real, you should do Complex * Complex(re = (2*Modelica.Constants.pi ...))

Comment: I edited the main question and added the error's code.

Yes, I have a problem between the Complex and Real, I tried to bring them to the same, but without success.